# Typed list comprehensions in Boo?

Tags: boo

I can't seem to grok the correct way to get a properly typed list comprehension in boo.  Since the compiler works by inference I'd expect that in this example:

```
fred as (int)
fred = (1,2,3)   # fred is an array of ints
barney = [i for i in fred]
```

the `barney` would be a `list[of int]`, since the comprehension is running off of a typed array.  However the actual value of `barney` is just an untyped `boo.lang.list`: it happens to contain only int's but it won't complain, for example, if I try:

```
barney.Add("A")
```

which I would expect to fail but which actually succeeds.

Is there a way to use the comprehension syntax to generate a typed list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rodrigo, the creator of boo, [provided the answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boolang/6RGoCijGRYM)

```
fred = (1,2,3)   # fred is an array of ints
barney = List[of int](i for i in fred)
```

The parenthesized expression generates the arguments for the creation of the typed list.